# Finding distance of one element relative to another with jQuery

Tags: jquery, offset

I have a series of articles that are repeated 10 times on each page. The structure is like so:

```
<article class="postWrap">
     <h2>Title</h2>
     <p>Here is text</p>
</article>
```

I need to find the distance the p tag is to the top of the article. So depending on the length of the title, the distance the p tag is from the top of the article can vary. The best method is most likely using `offset()` but I'm having trouble getting it to work correctly.

Thanks

UPDATE:

Here is the working code I wrote, but I would imagine there is a better way of going about it:

```
$(".postWrap").each(function(){
        var postWrap = $(this).offset().top;
        var firstP = $(this).find("p:first-of-type").offset().top;
        var diff = firstP - postWrap;
        var meta = $(this).find(".meta").css({'marginTop' : diff})

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your question that there is always exactly one `<h2>` element preceding your first `<p>` you could use the height (`outerHeight`) of the `<h2>` element instead of calculating the offset as a shortcut:

```
$(".postWrap").each(function(){
    var diff = $(this).find('h2:first').outerHeight();
    var meta = $(this).find(".meta").css('margin-top', diff);
});
```

From your example I did not get what `.meta` is, but you could try that and tell me if it works as expected. You could also use `innerHeight` if that fits better.

EDIT: Or as a "one-liner" without declaring variables:

```
$(".postWrap").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".meta").css(
        'margin-top', 
        $(this).find('h2:first').outerHeight()
    );
});
```